# How to validate each entry of arraylist of java in a groovy test case

Tags: java, groovy, bdd, spock

We are using spock framework (groovy language) to write test cases for our java code.

I am new to groovy and spock framework.

I am trying to validate values contained in a hashmap

I have a class like this:

```
public class Properties{

protected List<Pair> property;

public List<Pair> getProperty() {
        if (property == null) {
            property = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        }
        return this.property;
    }

}

public class Pair {

protected String name;
protected String surname;

...getters and setters

}
```

In the spock framework, the test case is as follows:

```
def "Test case"(){

given:

....
....

when:
...
...

then:
...

def pairs = getProperties().getProperty()

pairs.each {

pair -> 
            if (pair.getName().equals("Anand")){
                pair.getSurname().equals("Zaveri")
                println "a"
            }
            if (pair.getName().equals("Rohit")){
                pair.getSurname().equals("Sharma")
            }

}
where:
...

}
```

Now when the name is Rohit, the list contains surname is Kapoor and I am comparing it with Sharma, but still the test case passed.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

The list contains a lot of names and I want to check their surnames in this test case.

Comment: Not related to your question, but it will make your life easier: you can use attribute notation for getters and settersspring-data-mongodb;, also: == operator translates to .equals(...) in groovy. Long story short: write pair.name == "Anand" instead of pair.getName().equals("Anand") - your code will be shorter and more readable. That's the Groovy way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add assert to each comparison e.g.

```
assert pair.getSurname().equals("Zaveri")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the classes are in the package `com.example`, the following works:

```
import com.example.*
import spock.lang.*

class PropertiesSpec extends Specification {

    def "test case"() {
        given:
            def properties = new Properties()
        when:
            properties.property.add(new Pair(name: 'Anand', surname: 'Zaveri'))
        then:
            1 == properties.property.size()
            // this is arguably not really testing new code:
            'Zaveri' == properties.property.find { it.name == 'Anand' }.surname
    }
}
```

The first assertion in the `then:` block confirms that the list was created. The second assertion confirms the specific `Pair` was added, though it is arguably not really testing new code. (There isn't a lot of "business logic" here.)

Comment: You may want to try renaming `Properties` to `MyProperties`. Or be sure to put the code in a package such as `com.example`. Groovy imports `java.util.Properties` automatically and there is a chance that is causing weirdness. If that does not work, please post a minimal example of your work online so people can see the details.

Answer (score 0):

Spock checks expression results under **expect** block.

val1 == val2 returns true or false and test will be ok or failed.

**Each** is not a java loop. It is a method which returns collection. 
So spock checks only that pairs.each{} returns not false(null collection is false too in groovy) in your example.

If you like to check each list element you can change you code to use loop, or you can put collection into the `where` block like:

```
void 'Test list of properties'() {

        expect:
        switch (pair.name) {
            case 'Anand': pair.surname == 'Zaveri'
                break
            case 'Rohit': pair.surname == 'Sharma'
                break
            default: true
        }
        where:
        pair << getProperties().getProperty()
    }
```